# Is it safe to use bit_cast for any aliasing puroposes

Tags: c++, c++20

I use `memcpy()` to alias data in memory. AFAIK that's the only legal way to do aliasing in C++ (aliasing rules are different for C and C++ are different).

Can I use bit_cast to have the same more conveniently. So is this legal code:

```
double aliasDouble( char const *p )
{
    return std::bit_cast<double>( (char (&)[sizeof(double)])*p );
}
```

Comment: Compared with this example I would say `memcpy` is the more convenient method, because that is an awfully ugly cast

Comment: `bit_cast` is expected to be implemented in `memcpy` way: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast#Possible_implementation and not via aliasing: `reinterpret_cast (or equivalent explicit cast) between pointer or reference types shall not be used to reinterpret object representation in most cases because of the type aliasing rule.`